# Ultrasonic anemometer: Transformation of space diagonal components to Cartesian components

Tags: geometry, physics, geometric-transformation

We have built an ultrasonic anemometer measuring 4 components of air velocity along the 4 space diagonals of a cube. The space diagonals can be characterized by vectors (1,1,1), (1,-1,1), (-1,1,1) and (-1,-1,1) in Cartesian coordinates. The measuring instrument delivers for each space diagonal direction a positive value once the air speed is upwards or negative once the air speed is directed downwards.

The mathematical challenge I am facing is to calculate the x, y and z components of air velocity from the set of 4 space diagonal components. There must be some sort of transformation from any three space diagonals to the right angle system. Actually there should be 4 of them which would allow for median values to be calculated. I am searching for this transformation and any help is highly appreciated.

For the technically interested: we have positioned 8 HR-SR04 sensors in the 8 corners of a cubic frame.

Comment: The problem is not clearly stated.  Can you add more detail about what you mean by air speed and how is it related to known parameters of the system ?

Comment: What would be an example of what’s reported from each sensor?

Comment: By air speed I mean values of air velocity in the specified directions given in m/s. These are calculated by comparing the distance between two sensors and the times of flight of the ultrasonic pulses in both directions. The sensor readout is a floating point number giving the value of air speed in the measured direction along the respective space diagonal.

Comment: So one of the diagonals is the segment running from $(0, 0, 0)$ to $(1, 1, 1)$, correct? And if so you’re given a single number from the sensor at $(1, 1, 1)$, the wind speed in the direction of the segment, maybe with the time of measurement?

Comment: The sensor in (1,1,1) measures the time of flight of the signal fired by the emitter in (0,0,0). But this is about the transformation of the calculated air speeds to the Cartesian coordinates of air velocity in the room. Change of viewpoint: imagine homogeneous air velocity in the direction along the positive x-axis. Projecting the value to any space diagonal results in a measurement of said value times cos (54.7deg). The values will be positive for the two diagonals rising along the x-direction and negative for the other two diagonals. How can I reconstruct the original value of air speed?

Answer (score 1):

My solution is based on the following:

(x,y,z) be the air velocity vector. The space diagonals a,b,c,d are represented by a:(1,1,1), b:(1,-1,1), c:(-1,1,1) and d:(-1,-1,1).

The cosine of any projection angle of any axis to any space diagonal is 1/SQRT(3).

The air speed value along any given space diagonal is the matrix product of the space diagonals and the wind vector times the cosine of the projection angle.

For back calculation I just do a matrix multiplication of the inverted Matrix from the used three space diagonals with the vector composed of the three air speeds divided by the cosine of the projection angle.

At least in EXCEL this reconstructs the original wind vector. Can anyone approve?

Comment: After waiting one month I assume, that no mathematician is willing to help. This problem is thus either too simple or physics applications is not exactly what peers of this group would like to consider ... frustrating!